# Answer that refers to tool deleted (but similar answers weren't)

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

There's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065247/how-do-i-calculate-tree-edit-distance) asking about how to calculate tree edit distance with 24 upvotes and 19 favs. The question is more than ten years old. These days, though, it might've gotten closed because it is quite general and/or is asking for tools. That being said, the answers are quite general as well, providing links to libraries, code, or papers.

[One such answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55879490/1150683) was posted April last year and deleted by a moderator soon after. From experience, I can say that this answer is very useful because APTED is a very good algorithm for tree edit distance (perhaps even SOTA in terms of complexity). The link is not dead, and the post is as informative as most others in the thread. So why did it get deleted (and the others didn't)? I would vote to undelete it.

Comment: Maybe this one was flagged and others weren't? Remember than new answers to old questions get automatically pushed onto a review queue ("Late Answers"), so they are more likely to attract flags.

Comment: Also "someone did it first" is a very poor defence of a post. Either it should be deleted or it shouldn't. The existence of _other_ poor posts does not justify not-deleting one in particular.

Comment: APTED is mentioned in another answer anyway. The only new thing is the link to the python package.

Comment: @yivi Agreed, but in that case I suppose you can read this question as: why were these answers NOT deleted. Two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @BDL True, but it is a different implementation of the same algorithm. The two answers don't refer to the same implementation.

Comment: See my first comment: they were not flagged. Also, not all answers to that question are of identical qualities. So flagging the others may be inappropriate.

Comment: What would be my correct response, then? Should I flag all other answers that are written with the same level of quality? [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065448/1150683) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1073816/1150683) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1905750/1150683) I know that it is nitpicking, but from a user-perspective the deleted answer is more useful (but invisible and deleted) than those others. Ideally, the deleted one should be undeleted, and not the others deleted.

Comment: The question is on-topic; but was closed because it attracted 'tool' answers.  That's OK; but since Shog is gone and the people who believe these are OK questions (it's Ok to ask how to do something, and it's OK to provide an answer that includes a link to a library) are gone; we're left with this.  Not really sure what to do here. Your answer shouldn't have been deleted summarily, but I would have downvoted it for not including information in the answer itself that would have summarized how to calculate tree distance with code.

Comment: @George, editorializing aside, the answer was not posted by the OP.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: For me, the referred question is clearly **off-topic** as it requests the code which implements **off-site algorithm**. Not surprising the question attracts 'tool' answers.

Comment: "off-site algorithm" when was the last time an algorithm was *invented* on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Tsyvarev If the question was asking where to find that paper, that would be asking for an off site resource. The OP is *using* an off site resource in their question. This would be OK, except the question is unanswerable if you can’t go to the link, open a post script files, or if it breaks. It should either have the relevant information added or be closed as unclear.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I probably incorrectly used the word "off-site". BSMP [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393382/answer-that-refers-to-tool-deleted-but-similar-answers-werent?noredirect=1#comment752122_393382) elaborates the problem better: It shouldn't be the only way for understand the question than going to the link, opening a post script file and reading the entire article-or-whatever-is-in-this-file. It should be either a **well-known** algorithm referred by a **name**, or the question post itself should describe the algorithm which the asker wants to implement.